# I am having problems with bluetooth and camera.

Tags: networking

I have just installed ubuntu on my laptop and i dont know how to access the camera and take pics using the laptop. The bluetooth for the laptop is unable to receive files from my mobile phone but the laptop is able to send them to the same mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Both your problem can be solved easily. Just go to Ubuntu Software Center and install,

```
1. Cheese Webcam Booth
2. Bluetooth manager
```